# finding occurances of substring of a string? why my program doesn't print any match?

Tags: string, algorithm

Recently I been given a assignment for finding number of occurrences of a string in another string, similar to how ctrl + f works. below is my implementation but I am detecting the bug in the code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int findsubstr(string s, string substr);

int main(){
    string a = "abcxyzcxy";
    string b = "cxy";
    cout << "number of matching found " << findsubstr(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
int findsubstr(string mainstring, string substr){
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    if(substr.length() > mainstring.length()){
        cout << "invalid string for matching!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    for( i=0; i<mainstring.length(); i++){
        int j;
        for (j=0; j<substr.length(); j++){
            if(mainstring[i+j] != substr[j]){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j==substr.length()-1){
            cout << "pattern found at " << i << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The code I found online is almost identical but my program never seemed to find a match even if there is one. Above example has two. my logic is to have i as index of mainstring and j as index of substring. then if all characters from substring match characters starting at i from mainstring, then pattern is found at that index.

Comment: For your inner loop put for (j=0; j<substr.length()-1; j++)

Comment: I just printed out what j was while i was in the loop

Comment: that didn't fix the problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i <= mainstring.length()-substr.length(); i++){
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < substr.length(); j++){
        if(mainstring[i+j] != substr[j]){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(j == substr.length()){
        cout << "pattern found at " << i << endl;
        count++;
    }
}
```

your logic is correct but the problem is that `j` is incremented to the length of pattern on the last iteration. 
Your program has a worst case running time of O(mn), where m is the length of pattern, and n is the length of the string you trying to find the pattern in.

In real life applications, ctrl+f uses more optimal algorithms that greatly reduce the running time when text is huge. Here [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) has a nice list of such algorithms.

KMP, for example, suppose you have a text `s = ababac` and pattern `m = abac`, you will find a mismatch between `s[3]`, `b` and `m[3]`, `c`. However, we know that `ab` in `abab` is a prefix in `abac`, so we can skip checking `ab` in the pattern and look for `ac`, however, this requires a preprocessed look up table.

Answer (score 1):

It is just because you are comparing j with substr.length()-1.

By the time it has matched j had already become substr.length(). So your comparison should be made with substr.length(). Below is the complete program.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int findsubstr(string s, string substr);

int main(){
    string a = "abcxyzcxy";
    string b = "cxy";
    cout << "Number of matching found " << findsubstr(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
int findsubstr(string mainstring, string substr){
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    if(substr.length() > mainstring.length()){
        cout << "invalid string for matching!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    for( i=0; i<mainstring.length(); i++)
    {
    int j;
        for (j=0; j<substr.length(); j++)
    {
            if(mainstring[i+j] != substr[j])
        {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j==substr.length()){
            cout << "pattern found at " << i << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: oh okay. Thank you!